# Incorrect syntax in SQL query near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error

I believe the problem is near the `(` next to `quoted price` as I get a syntax error of `Incorrect syntax near '('`.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Using Microsoft SQL-Server Management Studio.

```sql
create view order_total as

select order_num

sum (quoted_price * num_ordered) as total_amount

from order_line;
```

Comment: `select order_num, 

sum...`

Comment: Missing comma after the first column (`order_num`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you haven't separated the columns you want to return by commas. The general syntax for the `SELECT` statement requires them:

```
create view order_total as

SELECT   order_num,
         sum (quoted_price * num_ordered) AS total_amount
FROM     order_line
GROUP BY order_num;
```

(A good way to stop forgetting comma's is by placing them at the start of the line, not at the end of them, as follows:

```
SELECT column1
       ,column2
       ,etc.
FROM   table
```

Makes it also very simple to quickly comment a column out by putting `--` in front of the line without your query breaking.)

Comment: And you also need to either remove the `order_num,` from the Select list or add a `GROUP BY order_num` in the query.

Comment: Thank you, I am definitely using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  I did go ahead and adjust my code to have the comma's in the correct spot, and am now getting an error of  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure order_total, Line 2
Column 'order_line.ORDER_NUM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ypercube: good point! Edited the query with a `GROUP BY` on order_num.

Comment: thank you both. i wanted create the view and order by the order number.  is there a way to do that, it seems that the select command has to be involve somehow?

Comment: Nevermind, i used the group by as you suggested and will use a order by in the next command i write.  thank you both again

Comment: That comma thing worked like a charm.  I just did my last code by placing them at the beginning of query and it def works alot better.  This place is full of tips, I shouldve been here as soon as I started class.  Thank yall again